# CSS Positioning: relate position define by negative margin

Tags: css, css-position, margin

how to make the boxes overlap and offset both top and left 5px one by one only use css

[plz check the result what i want first](http://jsfiddle.net/minzojian/b83papyn/2/)

plz check the upper link

i thought it can be done in just one style define,no need to define each box's location

can u help me adjust it in [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/minzojian/b83papyn/1/)?

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="card" ></div>
    <div class="card" ></div>
    <div class="card" ></div>
    <div class="card" ></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
display:block; 
font-size: 0;
}
.card{
position:relative;
background:red;
opacity: 0.4;
width:40px;
height:60px;
margin-top:-55px;
margin-left:-35px;
}
```

thank u vv much

Answer (score 0):

How about minimalising markup and using a box shadow instead?

this allows you to only declare a single card element, and use multiple box shadows:

```css
.holder{
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
display:block; 
font-size: 0;
}
.card{
position:relative;
background:red;
opacity: 0.4;
width:40px;
height:60px;
margin-top:-55px;
margin-left:-35px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(255,0,0,0.4),10px 10px rgba(255,0,0,0.4), 15px 15px rgba(255,0,0,0.4), 20px 20px rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="card" ></div>
</div>
```